# Android Studio uses CPU 100% in Windows 10 for more than 10 hours

Tags: android-studio, cpu, cpu-usage

The Android Studio 3.4.1 has many sub-processes (around 100!) as seen by the following screen-cap:

Windows 10 Task Manager Screen Shot - more than 90 sub-processes under process Android Studio, and CPU usage keep 100% for more than 10 hours!

[image: Windows 10 Task Manager Screen Shot - more than 90 sub-processes under process Android Studio, and CPU usage keep 100% for more than 10 hours!]

**My only question is: how can I solve this CPU 100% problem?**

But I would like to use the following questions/answers section to provide more information about the problem!

Qus 1: What am I doing inside Android Studio?

Ans 1: Absolutely nothing, the sub-processes are there even I closed all projects. (But with Android Studio opened)

Qus 2: What is my hardware/software configuration?

Ans 2: CPU: Intel Core i5-6200U 2.3GHz, Ram: 8GB DDR3, Harddisk: 250GB SSD + 1TB Harddisk, OS: Windows 10 Home, verion 1803, Android Studio Version: 3.4.1

Qus 3: How many sub-processes? What are their names?

Ans 3: There are around 45 'Window Command Processor' and another 45 'Console Window Host' sub-processes under the process 'Android Studio'.

Qus 4: What did I do in order to get rid of the cpu-usage problem?

Ans 4.1: Uninstall and Re-install Android Studio

Ans 4.2: Clicked 'Help' -> 'Edit Custom VM-options' and set the following

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

then restart Android Studio

Ans 4.3: Wait for the sub-processes to complete, but it's been 10 hours.

Ans 4.4: Open a project and set the following in android/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

Ans 4.5: Close all projects. (But with Android Studio opened)

Ans 4.6: Search all stackoverflow and google, for related problems, none of them has this 'Many sub-processes AND 100% cpu-usage' problem.

Comment: If you intend on answering your own question, **you need to write an actual question**. See [the self-answering guide](/help/self-answer), as well as [ask] and [answer]

Comment: No, I'm not intended to answer my own questions, those questions are only to clarify the problems.  I try to use the 'New Format' of stackoverflow to clarify the problem, such as 'What did you do to solve the problem?' -> 'I did blablabla in order to solve the problem but not succeeded'.

Comment: Then please clarify that. In its current state, this doesn't really look like a question

Comment: @Zoe, great idea!  I've just updated the question.

Comment: @Zephan did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, maybe you have other problems, but Android Studio 3.2+ is using processor on 100%.

There is no fix for now.

You can do two things:

- Remove Android Studio and all related files, then install a fresh version
- Check for Windows updates

Comment: Hi Said, thanks for your response, I googled and checked stackoverflow, the others are having this problem usually on compiling or typing codes.  But I already CLOSED ALL PROJECTS, which means that Android Studio should not be in the state of compiling, coding, indexing, whatever!  It's doing nothing at all.  Is this still a 'KNOWN ISSUE'?  I thought I was the first one getting this issue!

Comment: it sometimes happen to even me but it get fixed after restarting, so you can try reinstalling AS

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete  Android Studio folder (in my case C:\Users\Andriy\.AndroidStudio4.0)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by lowering the max heap size

Go to Settings->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Memory Settings
lower to min values (my PC has 16GB RAM)

[image: my PC have 16GB RAM]